# Chrome loads webpages a lot slower when refreshing than when typing in the omnibox

Tags: google-chrome

Unfortunately on google chrome when refreshing webpages it loads very slowly. For example if I pressed refresh now it would take 10 seconds to refresh. However if I opened a new tab and typed in superuser it would load a lot quicker. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I was thinking caching when i started reading but that affect omnibox search to, you could try clearing the cache but i have feeling it wont work

Comment: Also when I don't go onto tabs for a while the webpage disappears and it just goes white. Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: mmmm i think i know what might be causing this then chrome://settings/ go to search and tell me the search being used and click set pages and tell me the pages that are set to open

Comment: It uses google.

Comment: what pages are set to load when you open it?